# determine when UINavigationController shows/hides when placed in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I have a `UITabBarController`, and in one of the tabs I have a `UINavigationController`.  I need to know when the `UINavigationController` shows and hides.  I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.

I can use the `UITabBarDelegate` to determine when a user clicks on that tab, but often the user is sent to this tab by another means.  I can also use `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillHide` in the specific view controllers within the `UINavigationController`, but I want to know when they `UINavigationController` as a group shows and hides, not any specific view controller within.

Answer (score 0):

Huh. Is there an instance method of the UINavigationController class that looks like this:

```
    [instanceOfNavController isFirstResponder];
```

You should check the developer documentation for such an instance method.